# Load complex-types in xsd-file from others xsd-files

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

Do you have an idea how to load complex types in xsd-file from many xsd-files?
see screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Show your code as a text, not as an image..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add schemaLocation :

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:transport="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/Transport" xmlns:SCRIPT="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" xmlns:ecl="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/ecl" xmlns:datatypes="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/datatypes" targetNamespace="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/Transport" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="NCPDPv2012AugustBallot">
       <xsd:import namespace="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/ecl" schemaLocation="ecl.xsd"/>
       <xsd:import namespace="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" schemaLocation="script.xsd"/>
       <xsd:import namespace="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/datatypes" schemaLocation="datatypes.xsd"/>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.programmatically? if yes, how?